# Div layers on top of eachother

Tags: css

I need 3 divs on top of each other, but am not sure how to fix it.

1:background image
2:opacity layer
3:text layer

The text layer content should define the height of all layers depending on content entered. 
Also the text layer should NOT be inside the opacity layes since i dont want it to get the opacity...

Any ideas?

Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Chris Coyier over at CSS-tricks has an example that may work for you:

https://css-tricks.com/examples/NonTransparentOverTransparent/

However it doesn't account for the text div being the one to set the height.

Comment: there may be some way of having the text div define the behavior of the other divs.  Something like #backgroundimage, #opacitylayer < #textlayer {